# Extract information through awk and sed

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

I want to extract ip the very next to `(axyz-pc)`. I have done this task through `grep` command using regex. But i need to extract through awk and sed.
`grep -Po '(?<='axyz-pc')[^:]+' logs | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'| sort -nr| uniq -c |sort -nr`

Logs:

```
2017-04-11 15:15:00 SMTP connection from (axyz-pc) [36.32.138.106]:1236 I=[10.10.19.36]:25 closed by DROP in ACL
2017-04-11 15:15:01 H=(axyz-pc) [114.225.87.41]:3823 I=[10.10.19.36]:25 rejected EHLO or HELO axyz-pc: HELO/EHLO - HELO on heloblocks Blocklist
2017-04-11 15:15:01 SMTP connection from (axyz-pc) [114.225.87.41]:3823 I=[10.10.19.36]:25 closed by DROP in ACL
2017-04-11 15:15:02 H=(axyz-pc) [36.32.138.216]:1984 I=[10.10.19.36]:25 rejected EHLO or HELO axyz-pc: HELO/EHLO - HELO on heloblocks Blocklist
2017-04-11 15:15:02 SMTP connection from (axyz-pc) [36.32.138.216]:1984 I=[10.10.19.36]:25 closed by DROP in ACL
2017-04-11 15:15:02 H=(axyz-pc) [37.49.224.14]:51593 I=[10.10.19.36]:25 rejected EHLO or HELO axyz-pc: HELO/EHLO - HELO on heloblocks Blocklist
2017-04-11 15:15:02 SMTP connection from (axyz-pc) [37.49.224.14]:51593 I=[10.10.19.36]:25 closed by DROP in ACL
2017-04-11 15:15:02 H=(axyz-pc) [36.32.138.106]:4619 I=[10.10.19.36]:25 rejected EHLO or HELO axyz-pc: HELO/EHLO - HELO on heloblocks Blocklist
```

Output should be(duplicate ip not repeat) :

```
36.32.138.106
114.225.87.41
36.32.138.216
37.49.224.14
```

Comment: seems like for given input, extracting ips from alternate lines will be unique and sufficient... if that is not the case, please change sample input for that case

Comment: @Sundeep, if it's a log file, there might be multiple entries with the same IP (all with those two lines)

Comment: @black, is there any particular reason to require `awk` or `sed` and not `grep`?

Comment: @likkachu I want to extract ip from real time logging, grep got stuck while logs running too fast.

Comment: OP's attempt can be simplified to `grep -Po '(?<=axyz-pc\) \[)[^]]+' logs | sort -u` if aim is just to get unique ips

Comment: If grep's getting stuck, it could be due to buffering issues. Look at `man stdbuf`.

Comment: I don't see why `grep` would stall, but `sort` requires all input before it can complete and return any output - it's a much more likely bottleneck

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why `grep` gets stuck, you will have to explore that further. However, there is no need for perlre here, something like this would do (at least for the sample you have given):

```
grep -o 'axyz-pc) \[[^]]*' | grep -o '[^[]*$'
```

Output:

```
36.32.138.106
114.225.87.41
114.225.87.41
36.32.138.216
36.32.138.216
37.49.224.14
37.49.224.14
36.32.138.106
```

Now sort numerically and apply `uniq`:

```
sort -t. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n | uniq
```

Output:

```
36.32.138.106                                                             
36.32.138.216
37.49.224.14
114.225.87.41
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use `sed`, assuming that the ip is in the first brackets:

```
sed -n '/axyz-pc/s/[^[]*\[\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p' x|sort -nr| uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

using awk, and telling it fields are separated with `]` or `[` and that we just need the 2nd field:

```
awk -F'[][]'  '
     {uniqoccurences[$2]++;}
 END { for (i in uniqoccurences) {
            print i ":" uniqoccurences[i] 
        } 
     } '
```

In the above example I also print ":n", ie the number of occurences of each "$2", but there is no need to do that (In that case, just do `print i` in the loop withing the `END` section)

The regexp: `[][]` is using the way regexp treat `]` and `[` within a `[...]` character class ( a `]` just after a `[` is then treated as a character to look for, and a `[` after the initial `[` (and before a closing `]`) is also treated as a character to look for. So `[][]` looks for `]` or `[`)

Another way:

```
awk -F'[][]'  '{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

A few options:

1. GNU grep

   ```
   $ grep -oP '\(axyz-pc\) \[\K[^]]+' file | sort | uniq 
   114.225.87.41
   36.32.138.106
   36.32.138.216
   37.49.224.14
   ```
2. perl

   ```
   $ perl -lne '/\(axyz-pc\) \[([^]]+)/ && ++$seen{$1}<2 && print $1' file 
   36.32.138.106
   114.225.87.41
   36.32.138.216
   37.49.224.14
   ```
3. awk

   ```
   $ awk -F ') \\[' '{print $2}' file | awk -F '\\]' '!seen[$1]++{print $1}'
   36.32.138.106
   114.225.87.41
   36.32.138.216
   37.49.224.14
   ```
4. sed

   ```
   $ sed -n 's/.*(axyz-pc) \[\([^]]*\).*/\1/p' file | sort | uniq
   114.225.87.41
   36.32.138.106
   36.32.138.216
   37.49.224.14
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat in.txt | awk '/SMTP/{print $7}'
```

gives me this .

```
[36.32.138.106]:1236
[114.225.87.41]:3823
[36.32.138.216]:1984
[37.49.224.14]:51593
```

For the final step :

```
cat in.txt | awk '/SMTP/{print $7}' | sed -e 's/\[//; s/\]//; s/:...//'
```

Edit : The above $7 will not work because the two kinds of lines have different field offsets for the IP address. A better way could be :

```
cat in.txt | awk -F "axyz-pc\) \[" '{print $2}' | awk -F"\]" '{print $1}'
```

We would use "axyz-pc" as the field delimiter in the first awk then pipe the output to the second awk.

Using sed instead,  would be not complicated.